# Will two alternators in parallel share the load all the time or will switch the load from one alternator to the other?

Tags: voltage, transformer, parallel, alternator

If two identical voltage sources are connected in parallel and supplying a load the load current will be the same since the voltage is the same, but each source will supply half the current demanded by the load.

This is used to supply a load current that one source can't supply alone due to overheating and voltage regulation. Also, this increases the duration of batteries connected in parallel since each battery will supply only its share of the load current increasing the battery ampere capacity.

However, if two unequal voltage sources are connected in parallel the lower one will not supply any load current and the higher one will supply the load and the circulating current to the lower source.

But in practice there may be tiny voltage difference between the two sources and the series resistances may not be exactly the same. In case of two chargeable batteries the higher one will charge the lower one and supply the load, and the lower one will be charged until the two batteries are exactly equal and start sharing the load.
In case of non-chargeable batteries, the higher will supply the load and circulating current until it reaches the same voltage, and the two batteries start sharing the load.

In case of AC sources (alternators and transformers) the two alternators are synchronized with each other and then connected in parallel to share the load, but in practice perfect synchronization is impossible and there will be circulating current and tiny phase and voltage difference between the two units so ... if at a time the two voltages are not the same will only the higher one take the whole load and supply the circulating current? doesn't this mean that instead of sharing the load together at the same time the load will switched between the two alternators whichever is the higher at this time? I'm aware that the circulating current works to bring the two alternators into synchronization but I think it is practically impossible to have exactly the same output (phase and voltage) from two alternators.

The same applies for transformers except circulating current will not try to achieve synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is practically impossible to have exactly the same output (phase and voltage) from two alternators.

If you disregard the voltage drops in the wires between the two alternators wired in parallel, that is, if you treat the wires as "ideal", then each alternator will have exactly the same voltage and phase. This is true whether or not one of the alternators is "stronger" than the other, or they are identical. It is a consequence of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL).

What may be different between the two alternators is the *current* flowing out of each one. Indeed, if one is "strong" and the other "weak", then current may flow out of one terminal of one alternator and at the same instant some of that current may flow *into* the attached terminal of the parallel alternator. That is the circulating current you mention.

> if at a time the two voltages are not the same will only the higher one take the whole load and supply the circulating current?

If you connect two *ideal* voltage sources in parallel with ideal wires in between, and the two voltage sources have different voltages, then what happens is mathematically undefined. Because they are in parallel, they must have the same voltage, but because we say they are *ideal* and that they have different voltages, they cannot be the same. A contradiction. It is like the question of what happens when an irresistible force acts upon an unmovable object.

So we must leave behind *ideal* voltage sources, and ideal wires, and consider real voltage sources, which have internal impedance (though it might be small), and real wires, which also have impedance, which again might be very small.

With real voltage sources and real wires, if the open-circuit voltages of the sources are "close enough", then they will share the load, perhaps unequally. If the open-circuit voltages of the sources are "far enough" apart, then one will take all the load, *and* feed power into the other voltage source. If the open-circuit voltages are "just right", then one voltage source will take on all the load, and the other will be idle, neither sending nor absorbing power. However, this goldilocks situation happens at only one (or possibly a few distinct) operating points.

Comment: So in practice if two nearly equal sources "close enough" with tiny voltage difference are connected in parallel the higher will not turn off the lower? Does this apply also to batteries like generators

Comment: That is correct. Yes, it applies to both batteries and generators.

Answer (score 0):

1. In practice large alternators (in the power grid) are perfectly synchronized, I think. The reason is the following. If  one alternator have slightly less RPM, it will  drift behind of the grid phase, so it will produce less current and make less drag force to the mechanical source (i.e. turbine, or combustion engine), this will cause the rise of It’s RPM. Such system will self-balance in such phase, that each alternator will supply to the grid as much power, as mechanical source can produce. The regulation target for each mechanical source is the right alternator current into the grid: as needed, but not greater, than alternator rating.
2. When connecting two “real” voltage sources (with voltage mismatch and internal impedances) it’s important, that the voltage drop across those impedances (under the load) would be greater than voltage mismatch. In such case both sources would participate in load feeding. And when impedances are greater, then participation inequality would be less.